# Issue with Comparator in java

Tags: java

I have an Employee Class like below

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private String jobTitle;
private int age;
private int salary;

public Employee(String name, String jobTitle, int age, int salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Then I have a Util class for sorting employees  like

```
public class EmployeeComparator {

    private EmployeeComparator(){}

    public static List<Employee> sortEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList, String secondarySortField) {
        Comparator<Employee> compareByName = Comparator
            .comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getAge);

        List<Employee> sortedEmployees = employeeList.stream()
            .sorted(compareByName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return sortedEmployees;

    }
}
```

This will sort employees based on their name first then based on age and it's working fine.Now I want the secondary sort to be dynamic, so I made a change like

```
public static List<Employee> sortEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList, String secondarySortField) {
        Comparator<Employee> compareByName = Comparator
            .comparing(Employee::getName);


       if(secondarySortField.equals("age")){
           compareByName.thenComparing(Employee::getAge);
       }

        List<Employee> sortedEmployees = employeeList.stream()
            .sorted(compareByName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return sortedEmployees;

    }
```

Now the age sort is not working, any idea why it is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compareByName.thenComparing()` returns a new `Comparator`, which you don't keep a reference of, so you never use that `Comparator`.

If should be:

```
if(secondarySortField.equals("age")){
    compareByName = compareByName.thenComparing(Employee::getAge);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the second comparator (`compareByName.thenComparing(Employee::getAge)`) as well:

```
public static List<Employee> sortEmployees(List<Employee> employeeList, String secondarySortField) {
        Comparator<Employee> dyanmicComparator = Comparator
            .comparing(Employee::getName);


       if(secondarySortField.equals("age")){
           dyanmicComparator = dyanmicComparator.thenComparing(Employee::getAge); // store the new comparator
       }

        List<Employee> sortedEmployees = employeeList.stream()
            .sorted(dyanmicComparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return sortedEmployees;

    }
```